# Greasemonkey script fails silently

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

I'm writing a greasemonkey script. A minute ago it works fine, then I add a few lines, and it breaks. Silently. It doesn't output any errors (in both `Ctrl+Shift+K` and `Ctrl+Shift+J` consoles) and doesn't run any statements. I even tried slapping `console.log ('hello world');` onto the beginning, to no avail - the statement doesn't get run. Unless I comment out all the code below it, then it doesn't run, confirming that the script is enabled.

There must be something stupid like a misplaced brace or semicolon, but Greasemonkey refuses to tell me what's wrong. Please help!

Comment: Show a sample script that duplicates the problem!  What OS, browser version, GM version?  If you run your code through JSLint, you'll usually see the syntax errors. Most likely in asynchronous or cross-scope things if the failure is silent.

Comment: "There must be something stupid like a misplaced brace or semicolon" - check your script with http://www.jslint.com/